# Denoise Node is"Disabled" but is working

Tags: node-editor, denoise

[image: Denoise disabled picture]

The Denoise Node is working but it is giving this warning. Should I change something? Note I have enabled denoise in render layers.

[image: D]

Comment: The two denoising are independent from each other. If you do nothing with composition nodes, but enable the Denoiseing in the Render Layers, there will be denoising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denoise is not working because your blender build has no OpenImageDenoise. What removes the noise is the legacy denoiser in the render layer which is not based on machine learning.

Comment: So how do I get the _openImageDenoise_.

Comment: If you are on windows the official builds should have openImageDenoise if you are on linux you can build blender from the source  or try from another repo.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem unfortunately if I don't enable it before rendering it won't work.

So, enable it before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue
I was using blender 2.82
then upgraded to the available latest version(3.2)
***and bam the denoise got enabled***